# svn:ignore property during import

Tags: svn, svnignore

How do I apply an svn:ignore glob recursively while doing an import?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "applying *svn:ignore* recursively while importing".

If you want to exclude a set of files from being imported you can set the *global-ignores* property in `~/.subversion/config` before importing. There's no command line option to do that on-the-fly.

Alternatively you may *add* the directory and delete the unwanted files before committing:

```
$ svn co --non-recursive <repository_url> repo_root
$ cp -R <project_to_import> repo_root
$ cd repo_root
$ svn add *
$ find . -regex ".*\.\(bak\|obj\)" | xargs svn --force del
$ svn ci
```

Although laborious I prefer the latter approach because I'm not a big fan of *svn import* (the *svn del* part is not common for me and I like to review the file list before committing).

Otherwise, if what you want is to set the *svn:ignore* property of every directory in the hierarchy before importing you must use the second method and do a *svn propset* (instead of *svn del*) before comitting:

```
$ svn propset -R -F ignore.txt svn:ignore .
```

(You may actually do a *svn import* followed by a *svn propset*, but not in a single commit.)

Answer (score 16):

You can't do that with a regular import; you need an [in-place import](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#in-place-import).

Comment: Thx for pointing me to in-place import. This solution is better than Romulo's suggestion.