# subversion ignore files on import?

Tags: svn, import, ignore

Is it possible to set a subversion property before the initial import has taken place?

I'm getting ready to import a web CMS into a new repository. It has the directory `sites/default/files`, whose files are user-generated, and I don't want them in the repository. So I'm trying to set up the property beforehand, but it looks like I can't, because obivously, it's not a repository.

```
$sites/default/files> svn propset  svn:ignore '*' .
svn: '.' is not a working copy
```

How do I do the import with it ignoring certain folders?

Comment: possible duplicate of [svn:ignore property during import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736856/svnignore-property-during-import)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply not possible. Import the folder tree without the files folder.