# SVN Import excluding files

Tags: svn

I have a project I'm going to be importing into SVN, but I want to keep the existing cache, index, media, etc... out of the repo.  What is the best way to do this during an import?

Comment: Which client are you using? You can add .svnignores, but it's easier to avoid them from the add operation if you're using Tortoise. In fact this is probably very easy in Tortoise altogether.

Comment: possible duplicate of [svn:ignore property during import](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736856/svnignore-property-during-import)

Answer (score 11):

I usually work around the selective import problem like this:

- Create the root folder of your project in the repository
- Check out that root folder, into your local copy root
- Now you can choose what must be added and/or ignored
- And finally you commit the root folder

Slightly more work, but more control.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the svn ignore list. Via the command line:

```
svn propedit svn:ignore ./path-to-ignore
```

Comment: I don't think you can do this because this directory is an import, not a checkout, so there's no .svn folder.

Comment: You can do this by creating the directory in svn, checking that out and either copying your tree into it (or just moving the .svn metadata directory from your checkout into your tree). Then you can add files and svn:ignores as normal, then commit.

Answer (score 1):

I would say the safest way of doing this is to try to get the cleanest possible directory tree prior to the import, deleting all the files you don't want.  Alternatively you can set the `global-ignores` value in your subversion client config file (`~/.subversion/config` on Linux/Mac, or accessible via Tortoise SVN -> Settings -> Subversion configuration file).

I'd suggest also setting the `svn:ignore` properties for each directory once you've done the import to prevent users from accidentally checking these files in.